# Ejabberd - Exauth authentication works but user showing Not Authoried to each other in pidgin

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I installed Ejabberd server and configured ExAuth for a php script. I am checking the chat with pidgin chat client on ubuntu and windows xp(in virtualbox). I am able to login via ExAuth (where users listed in my mysql database) in both ubuntu and windows with different users.
However They are unable to chat each other as each other status is showing as Not Authorized.

Early I checked with internal auth_method. Where i added two users via web admin, and then login both at windows and linux machine. When i add buddy, then request goes to other user, After request approval by other user, Chat was worked. But in ExAuth Even after sending request, Other user did not receive any request.

If any body know where can be the problem area ?

Comment: One more thing, I want to add that I also tried odbc with mysql. It is working fine with authentication+chat but plain-text password is big bottleneck as it is hard to convince client to give a solution having plain text passwords in DB Tables.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64981/ejabberd-enigmaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing authentication (allowing to open an XMPP session on the server) and presence subscription as defined in the roster (you should still be able to chat presence subscription is Independant from messaging).

Comment: I don't have idea of chat presence subscription concept. I just enable  the `{auth_method,external}` and `{extauth_program,php_script_path}`. In script I write authenticate function which authenticate users (exists in My DB) login  on pidgin client. Now if one of try to add buddy, Other does not get request and buddy added as `not authorized` in former user's list.

Comment: Also there are no log for this request either in erlang.log / ejabberd.log. So unable to understand what is done behind the scene. I also implemented `isuser` functionality but results still same.

Comment: Finally it is done. I added isuser API Call and restart server. Now it is working.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj can you please explain about the API.
I am trying extauth and I have the script in place.
User login is working but says not authorized and there is no presence.
How can I call the isuser API?